# Integration of $\int\frac{e^{x}}{\sqrt{x}} dx $

Tags: integration, exponential-function

How do I integrate 
$\int\frac{e^{x}}{\sqrt{x}} dx $

I can't think of a suitable substitution. Is it even possible?

Comment: Look what you get when you substitute $y=\sqrt{x}$

Comment: I then get $\int\frac{-e^{y^2}}{2} dy$... that doesn't help, does it? Or should I refresh my standard integrals? That $y^2$ is now a problem...

Comment: I know about few people betting with friends on calculating such integrals...

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible using elementary functions. After substituting $y= i \sqrt{x}$ you will get the [integral of a Gaussian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Comment: Wow... Interesting. Thank you so much!